# Find previous power of 2 in 64 bit number

Tags: c++, bit

// Objective : Verify 64 bit input is power of 2.If number is not power of 2, find the previous value , which is power of 2.

using namespace std;

int main()
{

```
//Input. 64 bit number
unsigned long long int input = 13174607262084689114;

//Check number is power of two.

if (!((input && (input & (input - 1))) == 0)) {

    cout<<"The number is not Power of 2"<<endl;

    //Find the previous value of input, which should be power of 2.

    //Step 1 : Find the Next power of 2 for the input.
    //Step 2 : divide the number by 2

    /*End*/

    // Step 1       
    input |= input >> 1;
    input |= input >> 2;
    input |= input >> 4;
    input |= input >> 8;
    input |= input >> 16;
    input |= input >> 32;
    input = input + 1; // input holds next number , power of 2.

    // Step 2
    input = input >> 1; 

    cout<<"Power of 2: 64 bit: "<<input<<endl;

}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: There's no loop in your code. Unless your standard library is broken such that it hangs when trying to print certain numbers, I don't see how that code could have an infinite loop under any condition.

Comment: ideone.com compiles and runs it and says  The number is not Power of 2
Power of 2: 64 bit: 0

Comment: I wonder how it compiles: code has 2 `{`'s but only one `}`.

Comment: i was expecting an output a value which power of 2 , which is lesser than the given 64 bit input value. But in my above code i get as zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
(!((input) && (input & (input - 1))) == 0)
```

This should be

```
(!(input && (input & (input - 1)) == 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears somewhat confusing. If you only want to get the next closest lower or equal number that is a power of 2, one way to do that is to simply count the digits in the binary and then shifting 1 back:

```
//assuming x is a positive number
long long closest_pow2(long long x)
{
    int c = -1;
    while (x)
    {
            x >>= 1;
            c++;
    }
    return ((long long)1) << c;
}
```

you may want to check for zero, if x can be zero.

Comment: through my code, i get the answer as zero.... which is wrong. i will try your idea.